# Cannot specify the tweets language when using the full_archive search for twitter API

Tags: r, api, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to download historic twitter data using Twitter's API. The issue is that I am not able to specify the language in which I want to tweets to be written. I am using Twitter's own language classification, but I only end up with the following error term:

> Error in search_tweets(q, fromDate = fromDate, toDate = toDate, premium = premium_api("fullarchive",  :
> object 'lang' not found

I used the following code:

```
rt_x <- search_fullarchive(q = "@hm",lang:"en", n=10,env_name = "xxxxx",
                           fromDate = "201801070000",toDate = "201801092359")
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo? `lang = "en"`? As it's written now, you're trying to create an integer sequence equivalent to  `seq(from=lang, to="en")`, but `lang` is undefined and that doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: I'm not clear which API library you're using to access the search API here, but in premium search the `lang` parameter should be part of the query itself. So the query string should be in the form `"from:TwitterDev lang:en"` but, yes `fromDate`, `toDate`, and `maxResults` (`n` here) are separate parameters, as you have them.